# How do I curry this function correctly?

Tags: javascript, currying

I tried to curry a function `add` using `curryDecorate`

```js
const curryDecorate = (fn, ...args) => {
  const curried = (...newArgs) => {
    args = args.concat(newArgs)
    if (args.length < fn.length) {
      return curried
    }
    return fn(...args)
  }
  return curried
}

const add = (a, b, c) => a + b + c
const sum = curryDecorate(add)

console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)) // 6
console.log(sum(1, 2)(3)) // 6
console.log(sum(1)(2, 3)) // 6
```

When `sum(1, 2)(3)` is run, I get

> sum(...) is not a function

It works correctly when running the 3 lines at the bottom separately,
but together it throws that error.

Comment: Maybe cose it is not a function? You saved just result from curryDecorate() in variable sum...

Comment: @ikiK the whole point of `curryDecorate` is to return a function, though.

Comment: Btw you also get same error for `sum(1)(2, 3)`...

Comment: It doesn't matter how you call it, but how many times, after it runs 2 times - it then fails, probably because `args.length` got bigger each time you call `sum()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you currently have one single instance of `args` that is shared between all versions of the decorated curried function. This means that once you acquire enough arguments *once* any further curried calls will just go directly to `return fn(...args)` and thus executing again will fail:

```
             console.log(sum (1) (2) (3))
//                           ^^^ ^^^ ^^^
//                            |   |   |
//args = [1] -----------------+   |   |
//args = [1, 2] ------------------+   |
//args = [1, 2, 3] -------------------+

             console.log(sum (1, 2) (3))
//                           ^^^^^^
//                             |
//args = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2] ------+
```

On the fourth call `sum(1, 2)` the `args` array contains `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2]` which is *more* than `fn.length`, therefore `sum(1, 2)` will execute the function and return `6`. The next `(3)` will attempt to execute the number as a function and fail:

```js
const curryDecorate = (fn, ...args) => {
  const curried = (...newArgs) => {
    args = args.concat(newArgs)
    if (args.length < fn.length) {
      return curried
    }
    return fn(...args)
  }
  return curried
}

const add = (a, b, c) => a + b + c
const sum = curryDecorate(add)

console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)) // 6
const result = sum(1, 2);
console.log(result)       // 6
console.log(result(3))    // error
```

You can take advantage of the fact that `curryDecorate` already takes `args` as a parameter, in order to avoid this error. If a curried call does not fulfil the argument requirements, you can call `curryDecorate` again with all arguments so far. That way you get separate function objects each with with a separate partially filled argument list:

```js
const curryDecorate = (fn, ...args) => {
  const curried = (...newArgs) => {
    //collect all into newArgs
    newArgs = args.concat(newArgs)
    if (newArgs.length < fn.length) {
      //call curryDecorate with arguments so far
      return curryDecorate(fn, ...newArgs)
    }
    //execute with all collected args
    return fn(...newArgs)
  }
  return curried
}

const add = (a, b, c) => a + b + c
const sum = curryDecorate(add)

console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)) // 6
console.log(sum(1, 2)(3)) // 6
console.log(sum(1)(2, 3)) // 6

console.log("-----");

const sum1 = sum(1);

const sum14 = sum1(4);
const sum15 = sum1(5);

const sum144 = sum14(4);
const sum145 = sum14(5);
const sum155 = sum15(5);
const sum156 = sum15(6);

console.log(sum144);
console.log(sum145);
console.log(sum155);
console.log(sum156);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Taking another step forward, if `curryDecorate` is going to be called with the arguments anyway, the logic to execute the function or not can be moved there and things are simplified a bit:

```
const curryDecorate = (fn, ...args) => {
  if (args.length >= fn.length)
    return fn(...args);
    
  return (...newArgs) =>
    curryDecorate(fn, ...args, ...newArgs);
}
```

```js
const curryDecorate = (fn, ...args) => {
  if (args.length >= fn.length)
    return fn(...args);
    
  return (...newArgs) =>
    curryDecorate(fn, ...args, ...newArgs);
}

const add = (a, b, c) => a + b + c
const sum = curryDecorate(add)

console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)) // 6
console.log(sum(1, 2)(3)) // 6
console.log(sum(1)(2, 3)) // 6

console.log("-----");

const sum1 = sum(1);

const sum14 = sum1(4);
const sum15 = sum1(5);

const sum144 = sum14(4);
const sum145 = sum14(5);
const sum155 = sum15(5);
const sum156 = sum15(6);

console.log(sum144);
console.log(sum145);
console.log(sum155);
console.log(sum156);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `sum` variable twice to curry, which only saves one group of arguments.

```js
sum(1)(2)(3) // args: 1, 2, 3
sum(1, 2) // persists, so args: 1, 2, 3, 1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This solves your problem:

```js
const curryDecorate = (fn, ...args) => {
  let pass=[...args];
  const curried = (...newArgs) => {
    pass= pass.concat(newArgs)
    if (pass.length < fn.length) {
      return curried
    }
    const val = fn(...pass);
    pass=[...args]
    return val;
  }
  return curried
}

const add = (a, b, c) => a + b + c
const sum = curryDecorate(add)

console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)) // 6
console.log(sum(1, 2)(3)) // 6
console.log(sum(1)(2, 3)) // 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const curryDecorate = (fn, ...args) => {
  const curried = (...newArgs) => {
    args = args.concat(newArgs)
    console.log('fn len', fn.length, args.length, args.length < fn.length)
    if (args.length < fn.length){
      return curried
    }
    const currArgs = [...args]
    args = []
    return fn(...currArgs)
  }
  return curried
}

const add = (a, b, c) => console.log(a + b + c)
const sum = curryDecorate(add)

sum(1)(2)(3)
sum(1)(2)(3)
sum(1)(2)(3)
sum(1)(2)(3)
sum(1)(2)(3)
  // 6
```